# What are stacks used for? Why are they in C++?

Tags: c++, stack

I've been reviewing C++ with the book [Practical C++ Programming](http://books.google.com/books/about/Practical_C++_programming.html?id=pXDzdJ_1E3oC), and came across these things called Stacks. Defined in the book, it is defined as an algorithm for storing data.

From what I've seen in the book, it looks a lot like assembly...I also recall reading something about something that is 16 bit.

So my question: What are stacks used for, are they still useful or is it an old method of doing something that can be done more simply and efficiently with 32/64 bit computers? I'm just really confused about what purpose stacks serve.

---

Edit: Since my question is so vague, I'll rephrase it... What is a stack, and when should it be used.

Comment: It's a data structure, not an algorithm.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 16/32/64 bit, when you need a certain datastructure, you need it, no matter how much bits you have.

Comment: Why is this getting attacked with downvotes...

Comment: @gabe I was just thinking the same thing. what is the harm in asking a question?

Comment: @Gabe Probably because everyone thinks it's trolling when a programmer claims to not know what a stack is.

Comment: @Gabe It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @WTP thats the thing... the book is ambiguous and vague. I'm asking for an explanation of what the heck it is...

Comment: @Eric what has this got to do with Apple?

Comment: @Gabe: The downvote button also mentions "does not show any research effort", which might be another reason.

Comment: @phresnel I researched the book. Read the chapter more than once. I'm confused, and figured I'd ask for professional programmer's opinions. Guess I shouldn't ask questions like this.

Comment: @Gabe: But have you also tried google? Wikipedia? Stack overflow? You also did not note the details of what exactly you do not understand. (Don't be afraid: Every programmer started small and we all had problems with what we now consider so trivial that we stopped talking about it long ago ;))

Comment: @phresnel I actually did look at stackoverflow, didn't find anything explaining the basics of a stack. So I figured I'd ask the question, which would also serve as a future reference for new programmers looking on stack.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Depends on which stack you're talking about.</strike>

The first is a storage location in memory.

A stack is a last-in, first-out data structure which is still very useful regardless of 16/32/64 bit computers.

As others have said, the call stack (or 'the stack') is an example of a Stack in action.

Comment: The call stack is also first-in, last-out. So it's not a different kind of stack - it's just one example of a stack.

Comment: I am being an arse, but a near 100k contributor who declares C experience should know that the "memory-stack" is an application of stacks.

Comment: @phresnel - I'd agree. And I do. Extremely poorly worded answer trying to show that the OP may have been reading about either the data structure itself or its application. Hence the re-wording. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: But maybe I was too much of an arse. Maybe you just meant something like "want an explanation of call stacks or want an explanation of stack data structures". Sorry if I was too offensive.

Answer (score 8):

Stacks are not a method, but rather a data structure, last in, first out (LIFO).

In C++, `std::stack<>` is a class template whose data can be any type. There are many situations where last in, first out is exactly what you need.

An example are virtual machines or interpreters that utilise a stack architecture to save the running state during execution of functions/procedures. Consider the following the interpreter of a language where sub-procedures may not change the state of the caller:

```
std::stack<RunState> state;
Instruction i = fetch();

switch (i.type()) {
case Instruction.Call:
    state.push (state.top());
    break;
case Instruction.Return:
    state.pop();
    break;
...
}
```

Wikipedia has [more examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29#Applications) for the use of stack data structures. Some sorting problems are solved relatively easily with stacks.

As with all data structures, and C++ has quite some of them ([lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28computing%29), [queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29), [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29), [maps (a.k.a. associative arrays, a.k.a. dictionaries)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28computer_science%29), [arrays/vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), and more), you may not need them now and maybe not even in 2 years, but you should know about them, their properties, advantages, disadvantages, and when it is the right moment to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, they are used when you need to store data in a LIFO (Last In, First Out) fashion. You can find informations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29).
Working on a 16/32/64/whatever bits architecture has nothing to do with the principle of a stack.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a stack in case of standard LIFO logic. There are a lot of problems that required the LIFO logic.